# Varnish rule for session variables

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I would like to pass the varnish cache if some certain session variable is present.
I.e.: if the user has a session variable named foo, I would like to have Varnish fetch the content from the origin instead of delivery the cached version.

Comment: Varnish doesn't really have a way of knowing about your session variables, assuming you're referring to things within, say, a PHP session object. You could do things based on specific cookies, if that's what you have in mind?

Comment: Thanks jdewald. Maybe I could change the code in order to control the app with cookies instead of session variables. I did one magento extension in order to show coupon discounts during customer store navigation. It works 'seeing' a session variable value and, apply the discount during category/product page render. The problem now is that varnish doesn't know about this variable and the application now is not recognizing who has the coupon or not.

Comment: You could just mark the "product" pages (or whatever else) as not being cacheable. Or would most people get a cached version

Comment: Thank you jdewald. I'm not seeing a solution for this case, because in most of the time I will have users with some code in session, and varnish will not do its job and I will need to put more hardware to handle the load. I have been reading about ESI. Maybe this is the path, but I don't have experience with this approach. Could you shed some light on this? I'm working with Magento and I need basically the price block not cached or retrieved from backend when the visitor has a request variable present in his session.

Comment: I have not messed around with ESI, but I agree that it is the likely approach for if you want Varnish to cache the bulk of the page but be able to have a small segment be per-user.

Comment: Thank you jdewald again. I will make some tests to try ESI and understand how it works.